# How to ensure result count and caching with varying parameters

Tags: rx-java2

I have an API endpoint that can different result count based on request parameters. Parameters are `page`, `per_page`, `query` and others.

```
fun getItems(params : Map<String, String>) : Single<ItemsResponse>

data class ItemsResponse(
  val hasMore : Boolean,
  val items : List<Items>
)
```

API is not trustworthy and could return less than `per_page`. I want to ensure, that I always get result count I need and cache remainder for next request cycle.
For example something

```
val page : Int = 1

fun fetchItems(requestedItems : Int = 20) : Single<List<Items>> {
    ...
    .map { buildParams(page, perPage, query) }
    .flatMap { api.getItems(it) }
    .doOnSuccess { page++ }
    .buffer(requestedItems)
}

fun buildParams(page: Int, perPage: Int, query : String) : Map<String, String> { 
   ...
}
```

Example scenario:

- Caller requests 20 items for the first time.
- Call to `api.getItems()` with `page: 1`, `per_page` is always 20.

  - Call returns 16 items
- Call to `api.getItems()` with `page: 2`

  - Call return 19 items
- 20 items were returned to caller and 15 remaining items were cached for next caller request.
- Caller requests 20 items for 2nd time.
- Call to `api.getItems()` with `page: 3`

  - Call returns 12 items
- 20 items were returned to caller (15 older ones and 5 from last response) and 7 remaining items were cached for next caller requests.
- And so on and so forth.

This looks like Producer-Consumer pattern, but is doable in `RxJava2`?

Comment: Indeed, I don't know exactly. However, I think that it looks like pagination, does not it?

Comment: It is pagination, but I have a case, where I must ensure specific result count. Someone requests "next page please" and I must return "per_page" count rather than 16 or 19 instead of 20.

Comment: Well fill the rest with empty or null values till complete 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: based on the additional info

Requires: RxJava 2 Extensions library: `compile "com.github.akarnokd:rxjava2-extensions:0.17.0"`

```
import hu.akarnokd.rxjava2.expr.StatementObservable
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.functions.BooleanSupplier
import io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject
import java.util.concurrent.Callable
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom

var counter = 0;

fun service() : Observable<String> {
    return Observable.defer(Callable {
        val n = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(21)
        val c = counter++;
        Observable.range(1, n).map({ v -> "" + c + " | " + v })
    })
}

fun getPage(pageSignal : Observable<Int>, pageSize: Int) : Observable<List<String>> {
    return Observable.defer(Callable {
        val queue = ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>()

        pageSignal.concatMap({ _ ->
            StatementObservable.whileDo(
                    service()
                            .toList()
                            .doOnSuccess({ v -> v.forEach { queue.offer(it) }})
                            .toObservable()
                    , BooleanSupplier { queue.size < pageSize })
                    .ignoreElements()
                    .andThen(
                            Observable.range(1, pageSize)
                                    .concatMap({ _ ->
                                        val o = queue.poll();
                                        if (o == null) {
                                            Observable.empty()
                                        } else {
                                            Observable.just(o)
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .toList()
                                    .toObservable()
                    )
        })
    })
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val pages = PublishSubject.create<Int>();

    getPage(pages, 20)
            .subscribe({ println(it) }, { it.printStackTrace() })

    pages.onNext(1)

    pages.onNext(2)
}
```

Comment: But this way if 1st page returns 16 and 2nd return 16 results I will lose 12 items.

Comment: From the question, it is unclear what the unreliability looks like in respect to requesting with different page numbers.

Comment: I've updated question with scenario in mind, hope that helps.